# How to calculate the percentage of a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some number fields and I want to get calculate the percentage of each value in that field. Which means I want to get the sum of the column and divide by it the every row and to multiply by 100. But it doesn't work. Can u help me?

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
select OrderQty * 100.0 / (select sum(OrderQty) from SalesOrderDetail)
from SalesOrderDetail
```